# Design Ebook Cover In Pages

Tags: pages, ebook

I have a pages document that I want to copy a JPG into and make the JPG take up the whole first page with no margins.  Then I want the rest of the pages to keep their margins as I've already specified.

I have the jpg copied into pages, but I can't make it any bigger than the margins and there is still a header and footer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about an actual ePub ebook that you create from a Pages Word Processing document, or just a PDF you create from a Pages document?

If you make the image **floating** or in the **background**, you can move it around without being hindered by the margins or other text. To make your object floating or in the background, open the *Inspector* window (with the blue "i" icon in the toolbar), then click on "Wrap inspector" (third button from the left), and choose your *Object placement*.

[image: Screenshot of the Wrap inspector]

However, converting to ePub removes floating objects, so if you want that, you should edit your eBook (using [sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/) for example) to add the first page back in. This is not too hard if you know some HTML.

Comment: This works perfectly.  I have it just in pages and was going to export it PDF, at least that was the plan.